# Language Selector from LWC Component

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, experience-builder-page

Is there any way to access the OOTB [Language selector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_language_picker.htm&type=5) of salesforce communities from an LWC or Aura component? We have custom Theme and wondering if we can include this as part of our layout rather than dragging it to the page as a separate component.

Comment: Reference here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_language_picker.htm&type=5

Answer (score 3):

To set the language in your community, you just need to set the `language` parameter in the url.
e.g.
`?language=en_US` or `?language=fr_CA`

Then you need to just put the OOTB language selector on your page somewhere and hide it, I usually do this with CSS.  I'm not sure why, but just setting the url by itself doesn't change the language of your community.

Comment: Just running into this issue. Display: none seemed to work but it is back to not working. What solution did you use to hide it?

Comment: Have you tried putting the language pick into another element, and then hiding that with `display:none`?